# Power BI: average measure not changing when filters change (like month)

Tags: powerbi, dax, average

I have a DAX measure in my Power BI dashboard that is:

```
Avg Rating = 
IF(
    SUM(data[Review Count]) = 0, 
    BLANK(), 
    SUM(data[Total Stars])/SUM(data[Review Count])
)
```

Total Stars and Review Count are both calculated columns:

[Table with Total Stars and Review Count](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YupX9.png)

My table has for product A:

> January - 10 reviews, all 5 stars --> (AVG: 5 stars for January)

> February -  10
> reviews, all 3 stars --> (AVG: 3 stars for February)

My PBI visual is coming up with the following for Product A:

> January - (AVG: 4 stars)

> February -  (AVG: 4 stars)

Should I be using a different DAX measure to ensure that the averages can be filtered by product, month, etc.?

Comment: can you show the data and how the columns are calculated??

Comment: @Umair, I added a sample picture of the table. I filter by YearMonthNum, Domain, Brand, and Product. I apply the DAX above to Total Stars and Review Count.